# python 2.7.13 where has the python console gone

Tags: python

I just installed activepython 2.7.13 on windows 7, and when I type python at the command-prompt, I get the usual version information and the >>>  prompt but the python console then immediately exits back to the windows command prompt.

I tried the same thing with anaconda 2.4.3.1 and had the same results.

Has the interactive console been replaced with something new or has it just been removed?

Comment: No, I think it was an error

Comment: There's something wrong with your installation of Python or `python` was pointing to somewhere else, check your $PATH